# Problem with BeginInvoke in .NET

Tags: .net, asynchronous, youtube-api, begininvoke

I have the following code to send a query to youtube and send the total result to a textbox. If I just alert the result, it's OK but I can't assign the result to a textbox. Please explain to me why?

```
private void SearchVideo(string keyword)
{
    string orderBy = "";
    switch (cboSortBy.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 1: orderBy = "published"; break;
        case 2: orderBy = "viewCount"; break;
        case 3: orderBy = "rating"; break;
        default: orderBy = "relevance"; break;
    }
    SearchDelegate sd = Search;
    sd.BeginInvoke(keyword, orderBy, SearchCompleted, sd);
}

private void SearchCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    if (null == ar) return;
    SearchDelegate sd = ar.AsyncState as SearchDelegate;
    Feed<Video> result = sd.EndInvoke(ar);
    txtSearch.Text = result.TotalResults.ToString();
}

private Feed<Video> Search(string keyword, string orderBy)
{
    YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(YouTubeQuery.DefaultVideoUri);
    query.OrderBy = orderBy;
    query.Query = keyword;
    query.SafeSearch = YouTubeQuery.SafeSearchValues.None;
    return GetRequest().Get<Video>(query);
}
```

And the error

> Cross-thread operation not valid:
>   Control 'txtSearch' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `BeginInvoke` so your delegate is being invoked on a thread-pool thread. You can't access the UI from that thread-pool thread; you need to call `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` on the control to then use the results on the UI thread. For instance, using an anonymous method:

```
txtSearch.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() 
    { txtSearch.Text = result.TotalResults.ToString(); }
);
```

Or using a lambda expression, and with a separate local variable just for clarity:

```
MethodInvoker action= () => { txtSearch.Text = result.TotalResults.ToString();};
txtSearch.BeginInvoke(action);
```

Using `Invoke` will make the calling thread block until the UI thread has invoked the delegate; `BeginInvoke` is non-blocking.

EDIT: If the problem is that `result.TotalResults` is the bit that takes a long time, do that bit still on the background thread:

```
string text = result.TotalResults.ToString();
txtSearch.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() { txtSearch.Text = text; });
```

Comment: BeginInvoke still block the GUI :(

Comment: @A New Chicken: What exactly do you mean? BeginInvoke is non-blocking both in terms of calling it on a delegate and on a control. Using BeginInvoke in the way I've described *will* work, and without blocking the UI. If you're having problems, please give a short but complete program demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Here is my project in C# 2008EE http://www.mediafire.com/?n220ddoi2i2

Please check it for me, thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Delegate.BeginInvoke` you might consider using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). A BackgroundWorker raises the `RunWorkerCompleted` event after it has finished, which *runs in the UI thread*, so you can update your user interface there.

Comment: I've already tried the BackgroundWorker but it's still block the UI :(

Comment: That's strange; I've successfully used BackgroundWorker in many projects where they *don't* block the UI. Are you sure you used it correctly? In your event handler: Just start the BackgroundWorker (nothing else). In BW.DoWork: Do the work. In BW.RunWorkerCompleted: Update the UI.

Comment: Is it possible that accessing property `TotalResults` actually performs all the work? In that case, you should move accessing that property to the background thread and just pass the resulting string to the UI thread.

Comment: I don't think so. The only method that doesn't affect the responsiveness of the UI is the one I post, but it's a non thread-safe and the Microsoft method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx still didn't solve the problem >.>

Comment: Can you try moving TotalResults in the background tread like Jon suggested? It's really the only sensible explanation as to why your UI thread blocks...

Answer (score 0):

Because access to Forms controls isn't inherently thread-safe, the debugger is warning you that you're breaking the rules by accessing it from a different thread. Instead, you can `Invoke` the control directly to get the results you want. There's a great, comprehensive Microsoft tutorial of how to do this **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(VS.80).aspx)**.

Comment: Using the thread-safe method take longer time than the normal :(

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. You can not safely manipulate UI controls on a thread different than the one that created the control; the debugger is designed to catch this (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(VS.80).aspx) for details).

So, you either need to call `BeginInvoke` on the control so that it is executed on the UI thread, or you need to set up some mechanism of communication between the invoked thread and the UI thread. Obviously the former can be accomplished simply with [`TextBox.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.begininvoke.aspx):

```
txtSearch.BeginInvoke(sd, new object[] { keyword, orderBy, SearchCompleted });
```