# Async version of generic extensions

Tags: c#

In C#6 I have the following extensions:

```
public static void With<T>(this T value, Action<T> action) {
  action(value);
}

public static R With<T, R>(this T value, Func<T, R> function) {
  return function(value);
}
```

Is there a way to have Async versions of these extensions?

**UPDATE**

I am adding an example to clarify. Consider (context is EF context):

```
IList<Post> posts = context.Posts.With(x => x.ToList());
```

Now how to do this if I would like to use ToListAsync?

```
IList<Post> posts = await context.Posts.WithAsync(x => x.ToListAsync());
```

Or

```
IList<Post> posts = context.Posts.WithAsync(x => await x.ToListAsync());
```

What should be the best approach and how would the extension look like?

Comment: BeginInvoke will not do any async, instead it will block the main thread when it becomes it's moment of execution...

Comment: `public static async Task WithAsync<T>(this T value, Action<T> action)`

Comment: @Gusman, new System.Action<int>(System.Console.WriteLine).BeginInvoke(0, (cb) => { System.Console.WriteLine(cb.IsCompleted); }, null);

Comment: @Jay That's not async, that's scheduled, it will not interrupt the execution on the thread and wait for it's result, it will schedule it's execution to some moment on main thread, it's blocking the main thread.

Comment: Well then that is Async, if he wanted to wait for completion that would be synchronous. He asked for Async.

Comment: async as a keyword is not the same as asynchronous calling. I interpreted him to want to asynchronously call the function, not await the return, although this does happen asynchronously it uses a Task, the semantic is really the same.

Comment: @Jay Using `await` does call it asynchronously. It *a*waits it, it doesn't *wait*

Comment: neither does BeginInvoke..., await causes a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Jay when speaking on .net about Async is about async/await/Task, anyway, calling BeginInvoke from main thread is exactly the same as calling it in some moment on the future, it's executed on main thread and will block it, so BeginInvoke is NOT asynchronous, asynchronous should be executed on parallel and free some form of threading resource, which BeginInvoke doesn't

Comment: okay, have fun, await creates a Task.. BeginInvoke just is a coroutine...

Comment: Are these the exact functions you are using or are the real functions different (for example, do they have more statements)?

Comment: I just added an update with an example ... Does it help?

Comment: `static void Test(int i)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Tested");
        }

        void Test()
        {
            var result = new System.Action<int>(Test).BeginInvoke(0, (cb) => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100); }, null);

            System.Console.WriteLine("Output");

            while (false == result.IsCompleted)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("NotDone");
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("NotDone");
        }`

Comment: @Gusman,Stephen Cleary, That doesn't seem to block the calling thread at all... Sorry, maybe it's you guys who need to see how BeginInvoke works...

Comment: @Jay it doesn't blocks the main thread `now` but it will block main thread `later`, on the moment of it's execution, async/await keywords take care of thread management, so it will `never` block main thread if the scheduler considers the function needs to be executed on another thread.

Comment: Blocked how? Not until it rests or has no other execution. If the caller wants an interruptable event he needs his own thread or a message loop which is what Task does anyway.... You don't need a async or await is the bottom line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081235/problem-with-begininvoke-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I will strongly suggest not to use `async`/`await` in your extension methods to skip generation of state machine**. Just return task and wait or `await` them when you need them

You can use your second method for async case too

```
public static R With<T>(this T value, Func<T, R> function) 
{
  return function(value);
}
```

Or you can constraint method for only async use

```
public static R WithAsync<T, R>(this T value, Func<T, R> function)
     where R : Task 
{
  return function(value);
}
```

Comment: Note that you can simply choose `R = Task` or `R = Task<R'>` given the author's original definition, so these specialisations are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I have a blog post on [asynchronous delegate types](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html). In summary, the `async` version of `Action<T>` is `Func<T, Task>`, and the `async` version of `Func<T, R>` is `Func<T, Task<R>>`.

I recommend you provide all overloads for maximum usability:

```
public static void With<T>(this T value, Action<T> action) {
  action(value);
}

public static R With<T, R>(this T value, Func<T, R> function) {
  return function(value);
}

public static Task With<T>(this T value, Func<T, Task> function) {
  return function(value);
}

public static Task<R> With<T, R>(this T value, Func<T, Task<R>> function) {
  return function(value);
}
```

Comment: Should I call the last two methods  WithAsync?

Comment: Personally, I would prefer them to be named `WithAsync`. However, there are also precedents to keep them the same name (e.g., `Task.Run`).

Answer (score 0):

Just do it as with any other function:

```
public static async Task With<T>(this T value, Func<T, Task> action) {
  await action(value);
}

public static async Task<R> With<T, R>(this T value, Func<T, Task<R>> function) {
  return await function(value);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this synchronously awaiting the async call?

Comment: You should add a `CancellationToken` parameter as well to the `Func<T, Task>` so that it's `Func<T, CancellationToken, Task>`.

Comment: Yes @casperOne, it should, but this is just a demonstration on how to transform the functions to be async, not how to implement the function's code.

Comment: Either way your using a new Task, see the answer above or use BeginInvoke.

Comment: Note that you can simply choose `R = Task` or `R = Task<R'>` given the author's original definition, so these specialisations are unnecessary.

Comment: @erisco If it's not specialized then you can't await as it can be something else than a task

Comment: in this simple example no, but in a more complex code it will do, if there is more code on the function await would be the right option.

Comment: @Gusman That is a fair assessment. The question will have to be clarified then.

Comment: await and async are the right option if you want unnecessary overhead, otherwise Task, Thread or BeginInvoke

Comment: await and async are the right option when you want to write async code in a one-function style. Any async process has an overhead,Task and Thread are true async and then you must manage it's states, check when they finished, synchronize instants, protect resources, etc, what await and async does for you automatically. BeginInvoke isn't even async and has the same (or more) overhead as await/async as it must be queued to wait for a moment on the main thread where it's not working, very similar to free/cacth a thread from the thread pool to await asynchronous functions.

Comment: This is not true, see my comment above as well as this test http://net7mma.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/112029#UnitTests/Program.cs and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081235/problem-with-begininvoke-in-net

Answer (score 0):

- make it `async`.
- make it return a `Task`. If you need an actual return type use `Task<InsertReturnTypeHere>` instead of `Task`
- and for good measure, name it `WithAsync`.  That will allow `With<T>` to coexist with the async implementation, and it's also common convention.

---

```
public static async Task WithAsync<T>(this T value, Action<T> action) 
{
    await actionAsync(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void With<T>(this T value, Action<T> action) {
  action(value);
}
```

Have your Action schedule a Task itself. `With` does not expect any value in return so it doesn't have to care how the action is run.

```
public static R With<T, R>(this T value, Func<T, R> function) {
  return function(value);
}
```

Supply a `function` which returns a Task. You can use it like `var y = await x.With(async z => { /* ... */ });`.

Conclusion: you do not need to make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the amount of processing you intend to do and how you intent for it to be processed.

Do you need a Thread? If so then using Task provides a good alternative to Thread.

Otherwise there are quite a few threads which may already be available in the Thread Pool for your to use, [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236493/active-thread-number-in-thread-pool) You can access these threads using 'BeginInvoke'.

```
static void _TestLogicForBeginInvoke(int i)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

        System.Console.WriteLine("Tested");
    }

    static void _Callback(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); 

        System.Console.WriteLine("Callback " + iar.CompletedSynchronously);
    }

    static void TestBeginInvoke()
    {
        //Callback is written after Tested and NotDone.
        var call = new System.Action<int>(_TestLogicForBeginInvoke);

        //Start the call
        var callInvocation = call.BeginInvoke(0, _Callback, null);

        //Write output
        System.Console.WriteLine("Output");

        int times = 0;

        //Wait for the call to be completed a few times
        while (false == callInvocation.IsCompleted && ++times < 10)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("NotDone");
        }

        //Probably still not completed.
        System.Console.WriteLine("IsCompleted " + callInvocation.IsCompleted);

        //Can only be called once, should be called to free the thread assigned to calling the logic assoicated with BeginInvoke and the callback.
        call.EndInvoke(callInvocation);
    }//Callback
```

The output should be:

```
Output
NotDone
NotDone
NotDone
NotDone
NotDone
NotDone
NotDone
NotDone
NotDone
IsCompleted False
Tested
Callback False
```

Any 'Delegate' type you define can be invoked on the Thread Pool using the 'BeginInvoke' method of the delegate instance. See also [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx)